# "Resuming from /dev/disk/by-uuid/..." message on normal boot

Tags: boot, hibernate, plymouth, tuxonice

I installed tuxonice in Ubuntu 13.10 and everything works as intended (resuming, hibernation). The only strange thing that happens is that it get a "Resuming from /dev/disk/by-uuid/..." message when I just boot up my computer that I usually only get when my computer really resumes from hibernation. The only diffrence between the two situations is that on a normal boot the dots on the splash animation change and on resuming are just static white.

How can I remove the unneeded "Resuming..." message on a normal boot?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Or more like is not advisable. That message is from the kernel ring and if you disable it you will be disabling all kind of important messages that could appear. So, if everything is working as intended and `quiet` is set in the boot arguments, leave that message there!

Comment: But I'm wondering why the message is appearing on a normal boot (after complete shutdown). Doesn't make any sense for me.

Comment: @joschi it tries to. Don't find anything it continues the boot.

Comment: And this is related to tuxonice? On the other hand it seems to realize the difference between booting and resuming by animated splash on boot and non-animated splash on resume. I don't want to remove the kernel messages but I'm wondering how to suppress the resume message in non-resume situations.

Comment: @joschi as far I remember, GRUB first look for a hibernation status, if that fails then starts a normal boot. Other than that I don't remember anything related to tuxonice.